# How to display dynamically array on input value change?

Tags: javascript, input, filter, nuxt.js, v-for

I have a `div`  in which I am displaying components from array of objects. Above the `div` I have an `input[type=text]` which will be filtering the displayed data depending what I will insert. It looks like that:

```
 <div class="filters">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Szukaj specjalisty" 
                   :onchange="filterAllSpecialists">
            <FilterData/>
        </div>
        <div class="all-fields">
            <SpecialistPreview class="specialist-preview"
                               v-for="(talk, index) in newTalks"
                               :key="index"
                               :name="talk.name"
                               :speciality="talk.speciality"
                               :hourly-price="talk.hourlyPrice"
                               :half-hour-price="talk.halfHourPrice"
                               :avatar="talk.avatar"
                               :rating="talk.rating"
                               :is-available="talk.isAvailable"
            >{{ talk }}
            </SpecialistPreview>
        </div>
```

I have created a method that takes the value of input and compares with the `name` from `newTalks` array:

```
<script>
export default {

data() {
    return {
        talks: [
            {
                name: 'Małgorzata Karwacka-Lewandowska',
                speciality: 'Coach',
                hourlyPrice: 150,
                halfHourPrice: 80,
                avatar: 'patrycja.jpg',
                rating: 2.5,
                isAvailable: true
            },
            ... more objects
        ],

        newTalks: []
    }
},
methods: {
    filterAllSpecialists(e) {

        let input = e.target.value;
        if (input !== '') {
            this.newTalks = this.talks.filter(el => 
 el.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()))
            console.log(this.newTalks);
            return this.newTalks;
        } else {
            return this.newTalks;
        }

    }
},
mounted() {
    this.newTalks = this.talks;
}
```

}

All I get is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name` in the `console`

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody answered and I have spent more time figuring out what was wrong with my code I found out that the first mistake I did was instead of using `@` I used `:` before `onchange` (I decided that for my purpose I needed `@keyup` instead of `@change`). Also there was an easier way of targeting the `input` value - simply by adding a `v-model='allSpecialistInput`.

So now in the template it should look like that:

```
<div class="filters">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Szukaj specjalisty" v-model="allSpecialistsInput" 
                   @keyup="filterAllSpecialists">
            <FilterData/>
        </div>
        <div class="all-fields" v-cloak>
            <SpecialistPreview class="specialist-preview"
                               v-for="(coach, index) in newCoaches"
                               :key="index"
                               :name="coach.name"
                               :speciality="coach.speciality"
                               :hourly-price="coach.hourlyPrice"
                               :half-hour-price="coach.halfHourPrice"
                               :avatar="coach.avatar"
                               :rating="coach.rating"
                               :is-available="coach.isAvailable"
            >{{ coach }}
            </SpecialistPreview>
        </div>
```

In the `methods` all I needed to change was the first line in the  `filterAllSpecialists` function like that:

```
filterAllSpecialists() {
        let input = this.allSpecialistsInput;  <--- here
        if (input !== '') {
            this.newCoaches = this.coaches.filter(el => el.name.includes(input.toLowerCase()))
            return this.newCoaches;
        } else {
            return this.newCoaches;
        }
    },
```